# Android: white screen while onCreate

Tags: android

I have an app that at launch inside onCreate method copies data from assets folder. It does it in three for cycles, each with activity indicator and the problem is that when first two cycles run white screen shows and only when third loop starts i can seen activity screen with indicator on it.

The code is following

```
Realm realm;
ListView list;
int[] imageidsm = {R.drawable.fon_sovety350, R.drawable.fon_german350, R.drawable.fon_usa350, R.drawable.fon_uk350, R.drawable.fon_fr_it200, R.drawable.fon_japan_china200, R.drawable.fon_history200};
String[] itemname =  {"СССР", "ГЕРМАНИЯ", "США", "ВЕЛИКОБРИТАНИЯ", "ФРАНЦИЯ И ИТАЛИЯ", "ЯПОНИЯ И КИТАЙ", "ИСТОРИЯ"};
Boolean firstLaunch = false;
SharedPreferences preferences;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    int height = metrics.heightPixels;
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;

    MainAdapter adapter = new MainAdapter(this, itemname, imageidsm, height, width);

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainListView);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (position == 2) {
                Intent toSssr = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TankListActivity.class);
                toSssr.putExtra("category", "СССР");
                startActivity(toSssr);
            } else if (position == 3) {
                Intent listActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ArticleListActivity.class);
                startActivity(listActivity);
            }
        }
    });

    RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this)
            .name("db.realm")
            .build();
    realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);

    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

    preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    firstLaunch = preferences.getBoolean("firstLaunch", false);

    if (firstLaunch == false) {
        firstLaunch();
    }

}

public void firstLaunch() {

    String[] arrayOfCatLists = {"00f.json", "01f.json", "02f.json", "10f.json"};
    String[] arrayOfArticles = {"32.json", "34.json", "44.json", "51.json", "33.json", "40.json", "41.json", "42.json", "52.json", "45.json", "37.json", "46.json", "36.json", "54.json", "35.json",  "43.json", "47.json", "50.json", "49.json", "48.json", "56.json", "58.json", "53.json", "59.json" , "55.json", "60.json", "61.json"};
    String[] arrayOfUsssr = {"62.json", "74.json", "75.json", "76.json", "63.json", "78.json", "79.json", "77.json", "81.json", "80.json"};

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfCatLists.length; i++) {
        new GetArticlesListFromDisk(arrayOfCatLists[i], i).execute();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfArticles.length; i++) {
        new GetArticleFromDisk(arrayOfArticles[i]).execute();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfUsssr.length; i++) {
        new GetTanksFromDisk(arrayOfUsssr[i]).execute();
    }

    firstLaunch = true;

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("firstLaunch", firstLaunch);
    editor.apply();
}

private class GetArticlesListFromDisk extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private String id;
    private int index;

    String[] arrayOfCatLists = {"00f.json", "01f.json", "02f.json"};

    private GetArticlesListFromDisk(String id, int index) {
        this.id = id;
        this.index = index;
    }

    ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String json = null;

        try {
            InputStream input = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(id);
            int size = input.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            input.read(buffer);
            input.close();
            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return json;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.setProgressStyle(android.R.style.Widget_ProgressBar_Small);
        pd.setMessage("Минуточку, загружаемся");
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String strJson) {
        super.onPostExecute(strJson);

        pd.dismiss();

        JSONObject dataJsonObj = null;
        String category = "";

        try {
            dataJsonObj = new JSONObject(strJson);
            JSONArray listing = dataJsonObj.getJSONArray("listing");

            for (int i = 0; i < listing.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object = listing.getJSONObject(i);

                String id = object.getString("id");
                String title = object.getString("title");
                String subtitle = object.getString("subtitle");
                String image = object.getString("image");

                InputStream inputStream =null;
                Bitmap bitmap = null;

                try {
                    inputStream = getAssets().open(image);
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Log.d("getArticleFromDisk", "Saved article " + title);

                ImageStorage.saveToSdCard(bitmap, image, getApplicationContext());

                if (index == 0) {
                    category = "Танковые сражения";
                } else if (index == 1) {
                    category = "Справочник танкиста";
                } else if (index == 2) {
                    category = "Танковые асы";
                } else if (index == 3) {
                    category = "СССР";
                } else if (index == 4) {
                    category = "Германия";
                } else if (index == 5) {
                    category = "США";
                } else if (index == 6) {
                    category = "Великобритания";
                }
                realm.beginTransaction();
                ArticleList articleList = realm.createObject(ArticleList.class);
                articleList.setId(id);
                articleList.setTitle(title);
                articleList.setSubtitle(subtitle);
                articleList.setImage(image);
                articleList.setCategory(category);
                realm.commitTransaction();

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}


private class GetArticleFromDisk extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private String id;
    private int categoryIndex;

    private GetArticleFromDisk(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String LOG_TAG = "GetArticleFromDisk";

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    String resultJson = "";

    ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String json = null;

        try {
            InputStream input = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(id);
            int size = input.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            input.read(buffer);
            input.close();
            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return json;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.setProgressStyle(android.R.style.Widget_ProgressBar_Small);
        pd.setMessage("Минуточку, загружаемся");
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String strJson) {
        super.onPostExecute(strJson);

        pd.dismiss();

        JSONObject dataJsonObj = null;
        String category = "";

        try {
            dataJsonObj = new JSONObject(strJson);
            JSONArray listing = dataJsonObj.getJSONArray("article");

            for (int i = 0; i < listing.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object = listing.getJSONObject(i);

                String id = object.getString("id");
                String title = object.getString("title");
                String subtitle = object.getString("subtitle");
                String body = object.getString("body");
                String hash = object.getString("content_version");

                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Saved article with id " + id);

                realm.beginTransaction();
                Article article = realm.createObject(Article.class);
                article.setId(id);
                article.setTitle(title);
                article.setSubtitle(subtitle);
                article.setBody(body);
                article.setHash(hash);
                realm.commitTransaction();


            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

 private class GetTanksFromDisk extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Tank> {

    private String id;
    private int categoryIndex;

    private GetTanksFromDisk(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String LOG_TAG = "GetTankFromDisk";

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    String resultJson = "";

    ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    Tank tank = new Tank();

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Entered preExecute");

        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.setProgressStyle(android.R.style.Widget_ProgressBar_Small);
        pd.setMessage("Минуточку, загружаемся");
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Tank doInBackground(String... params) {

        String json = null;

        try {
            InputStream input = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(id);
            int size = input.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            input.read(buffer);
            input.close();
            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        JSONObject dataJsonObj = null;
        String category = "";

        try {
            dataJsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
            JSONArray listing = dataJsonObj.getJSONArray("article");

            for (int i = 0; i < listing.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object = listing.getJSONObject(i);

                String id = object.getString("id");
                String title = object.getString("title");
                JSONArray signatures = object.getJSONArray("signatures");

                ArrayList<String> signatures_list = new ArrayList<String>();

                for (int j = 0; j < signatures.length(); j++) {
                    signatures_list.add(signatures.get(j).toString());
                }

                String signatures_string = Joiner.on(",").join(signatures_list);

                String body = object.getString("body");
                String construction = object.getString("construction");
                String modification = object.getString("modification");
                String ttx = object.getString("ttx");
                JSONObject images = object.getJSONObject("images");
                JSONArray tank_slider = images.getJSONArray("tank_slider");

                ArrayList<String> tank_slider_list = new ArrayList<String>();

                for (int k = 0; k < tank_slider.length(); k++) {

                    InputStream inputStream =null;
                    Bitmap bitmap = null;

                    try {
                        inputStream = getAssets().open(tank_slider.getString(k));
                        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                    ImageStorage.saveToSdCard(bitmap, tank_slider.getString(k), getApplicationContext());

                    tank_slider_list.add(tank_slider.getString(k));
                }

                String tank_slider_string = Joiner.on(",").join(tank_slider_list);

                String hash = object.getString("content_version");

                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Imported from assets tank with id " + id);

                tank.setId(id);
                tank.setTitle(title);
                tank.setSignatures(signatures_string);
                tank.setBody(body);
                tank.setConstruction(construction);
                tank.setModification(modification);
                tank.setTtx(ttx);
                tank.setTank_slider(tank_slider_string);
                tank.setHash(hash);

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return tank;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Tank tank) {
        super.onPostExecute(tank);

        pd.dismiss();

        realm.beginTransaction();
        Tank newTank = realm.createObject(Tank.class);
        newTank.setId(tank.getId());
        newTank.setTitle(tank.getTitle());
        newTank.setSignatures(tank.getSignatures());
        newTank.setBody(tank.getBody());
        newTank.setConstruction(tank.getConstruction());
        newTank.setModification(tank.getModification());
        newTank.setTtx(tank.getTtx());
        newTank.setTank_slider(tank.getTank_slider());
        newTank.setHash(tank.getHash());
        realm.commitTransaction();

    }
}
```

What Im I doing wrong ?

Comment: All three tasks are running on top of each other. With regards to the blank screen, you aren't displaying anything other than some progress dialogs.

Comment: inside onCreate I also have references to views so it is not completely empty and that views are being shown lately. but why it shows only after third async task begins ?

Comment: Still, your AsyncTasks are only loading data into Realm, so they aren't affecting the ListView being displayed.

Comment: yes. and I completely dont understand what and why it happens :(

Comment: If you just comment out the line that calls `firstLaunch()`, what happens?

Comment: then it runs okay, UI shows instantly

Comment: Right. So, the ProgressDialog is being shown on the UI thread and temporarily locking anything else from being displayed. If that is a problem, then simply don't use the ProgressDialog and use some TextView or ProgressBar somewhere that you can toggle.